# How to store multiple image in a single file

Tags: vb.net

I want to store images like finger prints and data in a single file so i can send that file via mail.Can anyone help me out here.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just put them in a zip file?

Comment: @Tridus, just post that as a solution.  I was about to.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is with a zip file. If you're doing it from the desktop, just use a tool like [IzArc](http://www.izarc.org/) or the built in zip tool.

If you're doing it in code from an application, [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is a library that can help you and has a lot of examples on how to use it.